# Should a custom find method on a Laravel Model be static?

Tags: php, laravel, methods, eloquent

In the following Laravel 5 Model should the `findByIdAndCourseOrFail` method be static?

```
class Section extends Model {

    //should this method be static?
    public function findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId)
    {

        $result = $this->where('id', $id)->where('course_id', $courseId)->first();

        if (!is_null($result))
        {
            return $result;
        }

        throw (new ModelNotFoundException())->setModel(Section::class);

    }


    }
```

With the controller:

```
class SectionsController extends Controller {

protected $sections;

public function __construct(Section $section)
{

    $this->sections = $section;

}

public function foo($id, $courseId)  //illustration only
{
     $section = $this->sections->findOrFail($id);   

     $section = $this->sections->findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId);  
     //would need to be non-static

     $section = Section::findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId); 
     //weird when compared with find above
}
```

On the one hand, we're not acting on a Section instance [See Note]. On the other hand, in a controller with auto-dependency injection through [Laravel's service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container) we'd act on an instance: `$sections = $this->sections-> findByIdAndCourseOrFail(7,3);` and my IDE (PhpStorm) squawks if `Static`.

[Note]: This comment may be a misunderstanding of how Laravel Models work. For me, I would expect that `find()`, `findOrFail()` to be Class methods and thus Static as opposed to the instance that a find method would return.

Comment: Well, `$this` is not available in a static method.

Comment: Of course, if the method was changes to static, `$this->` would be changed to `self::`

Comment: But then `where()` and `first()` need a change as well, and perhaps then the entire `Model` if those methods are defined there.

Comment: Why would where(), and first(0 need to be changed? These methods are defined (or accessible) within the Laravel Eloquent Model Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes) are meant to be used like that. But it works for me on laravel 5.2:

```
public function scopeFindByIdAndCourseOrFail($query, $id, $courseId)
{
    $result = $query->where('id', $id)->where('course_id', $courseId)->first();

    if (!is_null($result))
    {
        return $result;
    }

    throw (new ModelNotFoundException())->setModel(Section::class);
}
```

In the controller you can use it both ways:

```
$section = Section::findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId);
```

Or

```
$model = new Section();
$section = $model->findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId);
```

Comment: This indeed is the correct approach. Looking deeper into the source code, none of the model methods are actually static. model::find() is syntactic sugar, so using scopes that retain the same qualities is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Section extends Model {


public static function findByIdAndCourseOrFail($id, $courseId)
{

    $result = self::where('id', $id)->where('course_id', $courseId)->first();

    if (!is_null($result))
    {
        return $result;
    }

    throw (new ModelNotFoundException())->setModel(Section::class);

}


}
```

Comment: The question isn't about how to make the method static. Rather, whether it should be static or not.

Comment: well in this case ... it should be static, it makes more sense to me. you call this method staticly so it returns a model for you.

Comment: if you already have the model, or it's instance it wouldn't make sense to call find on it

Comment: That's not the case though with auto-dependency injection through Laravel's service container. Controllers have an instance of the class injected automatically using PHPs reflection mechanism. On these instances you can indeed call `find`.

Comment: this is really hard and I don't think there is one answer, so I'm gonna go with my intuition and say it should be static.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would make this a static method, I'm not sure if there is a "correct" answer though as either can be done. The way I kind of separate them in my mind is if I'm doing something to an instance of a model then I make it a normal public function. If I am doing something to the Collection I use a static. For example:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setAdmin(true);
$person->save();

// OR

$admins = Person::getAdmins();
```

In the first example we have a specific instance of a `Person` and we are manipulating it, all code would be simply manipulating that specific instance. In the second example we are acting on the entire collection of `Person` and we want a collection of objects to be returned.

In your case you would have to initiate an instance of `Section` just to be able to use your non-static public method, like this:

```
$section = new Section();
$foundSection = $section->findByIdAndCourseOrFail(7,3);
```

So `$section` becomes a temporary variable that is never really used. On the other hand if you made it a static you could call it without having to do this.

```
$section = Section::findByIdAndCourseOrFail(7,3);
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Regarding: "In your case you would have to initiate an instance of Section just to be able to use your non-static public method, like this". In fact, this is not the case. In the controller, I use reflection and the instance is automatically injected into the constructor. `public function __construct(Section $sections){ $this->sections = $sections}` and in this case static makes less sense although generally I work along the logic that you do hence the question!

Comment: Regardless I don't think I would make an exception just for this case. What if you need to use that function somewhere else at a different time? I would stick to your standards.

Comment: I don't think this is making an exception. Automatic injection with the service container is used extensively, and the `find()` method itself is not called statically, and making it static would nullify the benefits of the injection as I would be making `find()` calls with the instance but not my `findByCustom()` calls which would look weird!

Comment: I guess, I'm looking for a more objective answer. Is the `find()` method itself `static` or not? It's hard to tell because it's buried in the `Eloquent\Builder` class, but it appears non-static. I suppose that refactoring to use a repository would make the point moot but this seems like overkill.

Comment: I've edited the question above to show the controller to better illustrate the dilemma.